# How to make paid app in shopify?

Tags: shopify

I have created app in shopify and now I want to make that app paid. Please let me know what to do to make that app paid. I want monthly charge for the app. I have already set price in the app listing. But its saying that you have to use billing Api and i have no idea about that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As Dave said, the Billing API isn't too complicated, once you get the hang of it. You need to create a recurring application charge using the API. Here is and example from the [documentation](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/recurringapplicationcharge#create) for the RecurringApplicationCharge endpoint:

```
Create a new charge called 'Super Duper Plan' for $10.00 USD per month

POST /admin/recurring_application_charges.json
{
  "recurring_application_charge": {
    "name": "Super Duper Plan",
    "price": 10.0,
    "return_url": "http:\/\/super-duper.shopifyapps.com"
  }
}
```

The newly-created charge will be in the `pending` state. It will have a `confirmation_url` property that you need to redirect the merchant to, so that they can confirm the charge. Once the merchant accepts, you can activate their subscription:

```
POST /admin/recurring_application_charges/#{id}/activate.json
```

--

Recurring application charges go through the states outlined in this diagram: [image: RecurringApplicationCharge state machine]

You should make sure that your app is only available to a merchant if their shop has a `RecurringApplicationCharge` in the `active` state. Note that it is possible for there to be more than one charge listed - for example, if the merchant declined the charge the first time, and then accepted it the second time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mikey,

Means i have to use above Api but the problem is I have no idea when to use this Api's. Can you please guide me about this?

Comment: waiting for your reply

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. You don't know when to use the Billing API? You use it when you want the merchant to pay money when they use your app...

Comment: @Michal Hewson, My question is I have to execute Api during App installation or during any event? Also one more query is if any customer get charged for first month and i am using recurring billing Api,then for second month I have to again use the billing Api to charge that customer or it will automatically deducts the charge?

Comment: You create a recurring application charge once when the customer installs the app. The customer will be billed every month as long as the charge exists and is in the active state. Hope that helps.

Comment: You means, after installing the app  I need to redirect the customer to confirmation url so that he can accept or decline the charge?

Comment: Please reply @michael

Comment: Yes, what you said is true. Is it not very clear in my answer? "It will have a confirmation_url property that you need to redirect the merchant to, so that they can confirm the charge."

Comment: I won't be able to help you much more on this, but good luck. If you are having trouble you can always contact your partner manager.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late to answer this question but my answer might help future visitors :)
so here is a process of creating the paid app in Shopify.
Basically there are two kinds of paid app available:

1. App that charges one time
2. App charges every month

Let me explain how these two apps working for newbie

App that charge one time: Your app will be a charge when the shop owner made an action or while installation, depends on App. Here is some API you need to should call to charge shop owner and get paid to your account.

1. Same as Recurring model charge. Only changes are you need to do these steps only one time.

App that charges every month is called Recurring Application Charge. App will charge shop owner on every 30th day. If Shop owner failed to pay, your app should be freeze. Let's start with API u should call. Api refer to [Official Shopify Website](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/charging-for-your-app)

1. **Create Charge ID to charge shop owner**, param will consist of amount,
   name of the package, trail (or not), and other things please check on official Shopify api linked above. Make sure you save Charge ID got from API response. All the below steps depends on it
2. **Redirect to shop owner to pay link**. You will get from creating **charge id API**
3. On Pay link shop owner either accept and pay else reject the charge. Shopify did not send any call back. So no way to know what going on here.
4. **Incase, Shop owner accepted and paid.** You will get Activate the Charge ID you got from First Step.
5. **Now verify charge Id is in active state** or not by calling retrieve single charge API and send charge ID you got from first step
6. Repeat these steps to take next month charges

Let me know if you guys need more information.

thanks

Answer (score -1):

Well if you went to all the trouble of making an App, then you probably want to spend at least a few minutes reading this: https://help.shopify.com/api/charging-for-your-app

After that, you know, it's merely minor coding to setup billing. Really one of the nicer things about Shopify, how easy it is to setup billing, and then get paid.

Comment: Thanks David,

Yes, i have already checked this above link.But still confused  when to use the billing Api. Need to add any hook or some other thing?